# One way binding ListView.Items.Count to a label (windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've got a `ListView` containing some records that I need to execute some actions on. I'd like to have those records counted on the execute button, so the .Text property of the button would say "Execute ([items_count])".

Of course items are added/deleted from the list by the user, so I'd like to have the counter refreshed. I was thinking about [adding an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041069/add-event-handler-for-listview-items-added) to fire when an item is added/deleted, but I don't want to create new listView class - I want it to be as simple as possible.

I tried to use [this code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/581/how-to-binding-a-property-to-a-label-control-in-a-windows-f.aspx), but I failed. What I did was:

```
// in the form's code:
public string ItemsCount
{
    get { return String.Format("Execute ({0})", myListView.Items.Count); }
}

// in the form's constructor:
myButton.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "ItemsCount");
```

And it only shows "Execute {0)" all the time.

Is there a simple solution for that, so I wouldn't have to change existing objects (like changing `myListView`'s class to a custom one that inherit `ListView`)?

Comment: I think you need to provide some sort of change notification once Items collection in ListView gets changed. check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz45s2bh.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide some sort of change notification once Items collection in ListView gets changed. check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz45s2bh.aspx) for help regarding implementing change notifications.

**EDIT**

I've brushed up info regarding WinForms ListView, and it looks like there is no easy way to detect when Items collection gets changed. Check [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169/is-there-an-event-that-triggers-if-the-number-of-listviewitems-in-a-listview-cha).

So I'm afraid the only option available here is to actually subclass ListView.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, as on the mentioned site it was said that the code above, without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged will set up one-way binding, which is my goal. I dont' know, maybe I bind the opposite way?

Comment: why can't you just subscribe to myListView.Items.CollectionChanged event (writing from memory, actual name of event could be different) in your form's constructor, and in handler fire INotifyPropertyChanged event for propertyName = "ItemsCount" ? You don't need to subclass ListView for this

Comment: That sounds like an idea. I hope I'll manage to do that. Can you provide a small sample of code? It would be helpful.